# R - Derivatives of the inverse of the regularized incomplete beta function w.r.t. shape parameters

Tags: r, derivative, beta-distribution

The regularized incomplete beta function I(x,a,b) is the CDF for a random variable distributed Beta(a,b). I have a problem that requires computing the partial derivatives of its inverse (the quantile function) w.r.t. parameters a and b. Do you know how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a closed-form analytical expression, but you can do it numerically (`numDeriv::grad()` uses Richardson extrapolation by default, see the documentation):

```r
x <- 0.5
## dummy (lambda) function with x from above and specified shape parameters
f <- function(y) qbeta(x, y[1], y[2])
library(numDeriv)
grad(f,
   ## shape parameters at which to evaluate partial derivatives
   x = c(1,1)
)
## [1]  0.3465736 -0.3465736
```

?

Comment: Thank you @Ben Bolker for pointing me to numerical derivation. What a fascinating topic. To be honest I don't understand your code: the \\(y) part and then the x = c(1,1) part, and can't get it to work. (If you have a moment would you kindly check and explain?) I'll read the package documentation and play around with it. Thank you!

Comment: It probably doesn't work because the `\(x)` notation was introduced in R fairly recently. I'll rewrite.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this version, and it works (without the comma at the end of the f <- line). Awesome!!!

Comment: "I highly doubt there's a closed-form analytical expression" -- I dunno, isn't the inverse of the Jacobian of a bijective function equal to the Jacobian of the inverse function? I.e., isn't the inverse function theorem applicable here? If so then OP just needs to invert a 3 by 3 symbolic matrix -- on the face of it, it doesn't seem difficult, just clumsy. Perhaps I've overlooked something.

Comment: @RobertDodier, my calculus is rusty, but this case is not that simple because the quantile function is defined by inverting the CDF as a function of x (treating a, b as fixed), but then I need to differentiate the quantile function w.r.t. a and b (treating the input p as fixed).